# contactPicker(_:didSelectContactProperties:) bug?

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

I'm trying to implement `contactPicker(_:didSelectContactProperties:)` method in  CNContactPickerDelegate and it's not returning anything. From a UI stand point it is making the contacts list look the same as `contactPicker(_:didSelectContacts:)` but it's returning an empty array.

It feels like a bug in the API since this delegate method should let you choose multiple contact properties but instead is making the UI allow you to select multiple contacts when it should let you pass through to the contact sheet.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? The rest of the delegate methods operate as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same thing here.

If you suspect it to be a bug, you can go to bugreport.apple.com and they will see if it is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it's not just me - I think it's  a bug so I'll report it